# /a/ and /q/ HTTPS links redirects to HTTP

Tags: bug, ssl, redirection, share-this

**tl;dr:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/24673359 redirects to an "http:" URL instead of an "https:" URL.

**Long version:**

First, the stuff that works:

1. The following URL works over HTTPS: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669940/java-8-missing-required-capability-require-capability-osgi-ee-filter-osg/24673359`
2. If I change the protocol to "http:", it also works (over unencrypted HTTP).  This is fine.
3. If I right click and "copy URL" on one of the answers' "share" links, I get an HTTPS URL if I'm on HTTPS and an HTTP URL if I'm on HTTP.  This is fine.

The stuff that seems wrong:

1. If I click on the "share" link (instead of right-clicking and doing "copy URL") a box pops up that gives me an HTTP URL even if I'm currently browsing over HTTPS.  Not a huge issue, but it's strange.
2. If I follow the HTTPS URL provided by the "share" link (/a/...), I get redirected to the /questions/... URL but the protocol is HTTP instead of HTTPS.  This is the thing that I'm most concerned about.

This occurs with *any* /q/ or /a/ link.